# How to power a large RTL project?

Tags: power, rtl

I saw [this](http://hackaday.io/project/665-4-bit-computer-built-from-discrete-transistors) yesterday, and I have been thinking about this:

How is all that powered *without losing any voltage or power over parts of the project*?
Would the battery just end up having more energy taken out of it faster as needed?

If you had any kind of batteries, then over time or over the usage of more transistors and resistors would make the battery less and less powerful, probably making certain areas of the project not even be powered. Multiple batteries at different parts? Individually powered components? So, my question is, how would one go about powering a large RTL project so that each section and gate locally has the correct/desired supply voltage?

Comment: In some countries on this planet they have so called power sockets in their walls that deliver electricity.

Comment: Lol but really that wasn't what I was intending on asking.

Comment: Then edit the question and elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is power distribution at your chosen supply voltage (say,5V) there are a few typical answers:

1) Thick wires, busbars as Connor says, to minimise voltage drop
2) Distribute a higher voltage, then each card has its own 5V regulator to maintain the correct voltage locally
3) Design and test each block for correct operation across a range of voltages so that it is more tolerant of supply variations.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is **DC Power Supply**. As PlamaHH suggests, you plug it into a wall socket, and as long as the AC power grid is working you get DC voltage out - just like a battery, except that it doesn't discharge.

EDIT - As for distributing that DC, you use wires to connect the supply to each module and back to supply ground (or "return"). And yes, you do lose a bit in the wires. However, the first thing you should learn about electronics is Ohm's Law, which can be used to tell you exactly how much you'll lose in any particular wire. Not only that, for a given length of wire, the thicker it is, the less it loses (This is why, if you ever try wiring a house, there are standards for what size wire you must use. Use smaller wire and you lose more power, which shows up as heat, and in the worst case you burn your house down.) Fortunately, if you measure how much current your each section of a project uses, you can sum them to find the total required, and from that calculate what size wire you need.

Comment: What I meant though is how does one distribute the power throughout the whole project? Just connect it all together? That wouldn't cause you to lose voltage or power at some parts?

Comment: @CelloCoder - Well, then use heavier wires, or buss bars, or something.